# SED inplace file change inside make - How?

Tags: sed, makefile

sed inplace change on a file is not working inside Make object.

I want to replace a line in a file with sed called in a make object. But it does not seem to be working. How can I fix this?

```
change_generics:
ifeq ($(run_TESTNAME), diagnostics)
    ifeq ($(run_TESTCASE), 1)
        sed -i -e "s/SIM_MULTI\==[a-z,A-Z]*/SIM_MULTI=TRUE/" ./generics.f
    else ifeq ($(TESTCASE), 2)
        sed -i -e "s/SIM_MISSED\==[a-z,A-Z]*/SIM_MISSED=TRUE/" ./generics.f
    endif
endif
```

I would like the generics.f file changed with that one line change. But it remains the same as the original. The sed command works outside make.

Comment: What command do you see being executed? What happens when you remove those conditionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this using GNU sed 4.2.2 and GNU make 3.82, or at least, I can't reproduce any scenario where the same sed command works from the command line but not in a Makefile.

Simpler Makefile:

```make
all:
  # Contrived just so I can test your 2 sed commands.
  sed -i -e "s/SIM_MULTI\==[a-z,A-Z]*/SIM_MULTI=TRUE/" ./generics.f
  sed -i -e "s/SIM_MISSED\==[a-z,A-Z]*/SIM_MISSED=TRUE/" ./generics.f
```

Sample file content in generics.f:

```
SIM_MULTI=foo
SIM_MISSED=bar
```

Testing:

```
$ make all
sed -i -e "s/SIM_MULTI\==[a-z,A-Z]*/SIM_MULTI=TRUE/" ./generics.f
sed -i -e "s/SIM_MISSED\==[a-z,A-Z]*/SIM_MISSED=TRUE/" ./generics.f
```

Confirmed that both sed commands fail to edit a file with this content.

To fix:

Probably, you need to simply remove the `\=` from your regular expression. The backslash there has no effect, and causes your regex to simply match two equals signs `==`. Thus this works:

```make
all:
  sed -i 's/SIM_MULTI=[a-zA-Z]*/SIM_MULTI=TRUE/' ./generics.f
  sed -i 's/SIM_MISSED=[a-zA-Z]*/SIM_MISSED=TRUE/' ./generics.f
```

Testing:

```
$ make all
sed -i 's/SIM_MULTI=[a-zA-Z]*/SIM_MULTI=TRUE/' ./generics.f
sed -i 's/SIM_MISSED=[a-zA-Z]*/SIM_MISSED=TRUE/' ./generics.f
$ cat generics.f
SIM_MULTI=TRUE
SIM_MISSED=TRUE
```

Further explanation:

- There is no need to specify `-e` there.
- There is no need to enclose the script in double quotes, which is riskier because it allows the contents to be modified by the shell.
- The bug appears to be `\=` and I deleted those characters, as mentioned above.
- Note that I removed the comma `,` as well in `[a-z,A-Z]`. I think that probably isn't what you meant, and it would cause a class of characters including `a-z`, `A-Z` *and* a comma `,` to be matched by the regex. (And if it is what you mean, you might consider writing it as `[a-zA-Z,]` as that would be less confusing.)

If this has not resolved your issue, I would need to know things like:

- What is the version of your sed.
- What is the contents in generics.f.

Comment: You should probably avoid running `sed` on the same file twice, though. Then you do need one `-e` for each command (or join them by semicolons inside a single string).

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, that's just me simplifying to test each command, whereas the OP had each one inside a different if conditional path.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX/GNU sed have `c` for "change":

```
sed -i '/SIM_MULTI=/c\SIM_MULTI=TRUE'
sed -i '/SIM_MISSED=/c\SIM_MISSED=TRUE'
```